# Not available for your current ubuntu version

Tags: software-center, steam, 14.10

I recently upgraded to 14.10, when I open the software center and go to some of my previous purchases it says that it's unavailable for my current Ubuntu version. Please contact the vendor for an update. I don't mind going elsewhere to get the software, but I purchased it here, so some of those transactions don't carry over to the games page and I am unable to download directly from the developer. For example, these are some that are giving me errors. (it pretty much just seems to be my previous purchases)
Steam,
Bastion,
crossover,
command & Conquer Tiberium Alliances,
vendetta,
etc.

Answer (score 0):

During an upgrade, Ubuntu disables any third-party software repositories. After the upgrade, did you re-enable them? In the Systems Settings application, under "Software and Updates", click on the "Other Software" tab, look to see if there is a check next to the Canonical Partner's repositories, as well as any other repositories you may have added. If not, just check the ones you want to enable, then hit "Close". It will ask you to reload, hit "Reload" and then give it a try again.